# LINQ-to-SQL Generic GetByIDs method

Tags: vb.net, linq, linq-to-sql, expression-trees

I'm currently using this to get an object by it's primary key value.

I'm trying to find a way to create a similar method GetByIDs where I can pass an IEnumerable(of object) and do ids.contains(pk), but there's no Contains expression.

Anyone know how I would do this?

```
Public Function GetByID(Of T As Class)(ByVal pk As Object) As T
    Dim itemParam = Expression.Parameter(GetType(T), "item")
    Return GetTable(Of T).Single(
        Expression.Lambda(Of Func(Of T, Boolean))(
            Expression.Equal(
                Expression.Property(itemParam, GetPrimaryKeyName(Of T)),
                Expression.Constant(pk)
                ),
            New ParameterExpression() {itemParam}
            )
        )
End Function

Public Function GetPrimaryKeyName(Of T)() As String
    Return Mapping.GetTable(GetType(T)).RowType.IdentityMembers(0).Name
End Function
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `Expression.Call`

Update - different overload

```
Expression.Call(typeof(Enumerable),
                "Contains",
                new Type[] { Expression.Constant(...).Type }
                Expression.Property(...),
                Expression.Constant(...));
```

Comment: I don't understand the purpose of "new Type[] { Expression.Constant(...).Type }" or what's supposed to go in "..."

Comment: That is the type of the Constant you are searching on. I am assuming pk would be an int